# Protein PDB/CIF text file reader that can fold a same section into one line

Tags: pdb, text-processing

Is there a software that can recognise the protein PDB/CIF files, and fold multiple lines of a same section into one line, so that it is easier to handle? I need to understand the format in CIF so as to create my own CIF file.

For example, when `Notepad++` is used to read a `.py` file, it can fold the same section into one line.

So for a PDB/CIF file, e.g. all the atom lines for a same chain can be folded into one line, and I can expand it if needed.

Like this picture, assuming "This PC" is the whole protein, while the other objects are the different chains.

[image]

Comment: You could try opening the PDBXML version of the file in an XML viewer that lets you collapse sections.

Comment: Thank you, the PDBXML file is 10 times the size of a CIF file. The 5TX1 has 100 MB. Can you recommend a software that is good for PDBXML?

Answer (score 1):

Programs that work with PDB and mmCIF files may present the structure as a tree, for example:

[image: ccp4MG screenshot]

(this is a Find dialog from ccp4MG)

but I'd be surprised if a text editor had such a feature. Normally, you don't edit PDB files in a text editor.

Comment: Thank you, I need to understand the format in CIF so as to create my own CIF file

Comment: @lanselibai do you want to create an mmCIF file in a text editor? why?

Comment: I am trying to do homology modelling for a virus capsid based on an existing CIF (5TX1, as the template) in the PDB database. The CIF template contains the assembly information, which I want to understand. But the CIF file is too long, which is very easy to get lost.

Comment: @lanselibai to understand assemblies you may start with [Introduction to Biological Assemblies and the PDB Archive](https://pdb101.rcsb.org/learn/guide-to-understanding-pdb-data/biological-assemblies) at RCSB's PDB101.

Comment: Sure, I will read it! Thank you!